# clear part of UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I've been doing some research on online for a project I'm doing but so far haven't been able to quite get it working. I want to be able to slide my finger over a UIImage and delete part of it, kind of like an eraser. I'm able to draw lines on the screen but can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you mask the image and when you draw on it, it adds the lines to the mask (in white, rest of mask is black) and then it should make those spots transparent

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this problem-

a) Determining the curve along which the finger was moved

b) Drawing the curve (which is really a combination of short lines) with the white color

For part (a), have a look at `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Using the `touchesBegan:` & `touchesMoved` methods, you will be notified every time the finger moves even the smallest distance, and the source and destination co-ordinates, say (x1, y1) & (x2, y2).

Part (b), As you know how to draw a line, now you need to draw a line from the source to the destination with the line's width (thickness) equal to the finger's. For that you can set the line's width using `CGContextSetLineWidth`.